# $[F:K]$ finite , $Aut_K(F)=\{f_1,...,f_n\}$ , there is $a\in F$ such that $\{f_1(a),...,f_n(a)\}$ forms a basis for $F$ over $K$ ; is $F/K$ Galois?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $F/K$ be a finite extension field , let $Aut_K(F)=\{f_1,...,f_n\}$ , suppose there exist $a\in F$ such that $\{f_1(a),...,f_n(a)\}$ forms a basis for  $F$ over $K$ ; then is $F/K$ Galois extension ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The given conditions imply that $ [F : K] \leq |\textrm{Aut}(F/K)| $, and this is a necessary and sufficient condition for a finite extension of fields to be Galois (in fact, this is how being Galois is defined in some sources).

Comment: The fact that $\{f_1(a), \dotsc, f_n(a)\}$ forms a basis does not automatically yield $[F:K]=n$. The *set* $\{f_1(a), \dotsc, f_n(a)\}$ could have less than $n$ elements. But it yields $[F:K] \leq n = |Aut_K(F)|$ and the other inequality is always true. So this is just nitpicking.

Comment: @MooS You mean that it does yield that $ [F : K] = n $, but that may not be immediately obvious to some people?

Comment: I mean that one has to be careful, when one says that the set $\{x_1, \dotsc, x_n\}$ has $n$ elements. This is not true in general. And when one reads your answer, one could walk into that trap. In this case, one can easily repair the proof, but there are other cases...

Comment: It implies that $[F:K] \le |Aut(F/K)|$ which implies that $[F:K] = |Aut(F/K)|$ and $F/K$ is Galois

Comment: I never doubted that. I just said, that one could spend some words on *how* the equality is implied. Because it is not as immediate as it seems to be...

Comment: @MooS I can't see how the set $\;\{f_1(a),...,f_n(a)\}\;$ could have less than $\;n\;$ elements **and still** be a basis (as linear space) of $\;F/K\;$ : if there is a repeated element, say WLOG $\;f_2(a)=f_1(a)\;$ , then **that set** cannot be a basis just as $\;\left\{\,\binom10,\,\binom01,\,\binom10\,\right\}\;$ is **not** a base of $\;\Bbb R^2_{\Bbb R}\;$ ...Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Let $G = Aut(F/K), m = |G|, n = [F:K]$ and $L$ be the subfield of $F$ fixed by $G$. Then $F/L/K$ is a tower of extension and $[F:L] = r$ and $[L:K] = n/r$. Also, writing $F$ as a $L$-algebra, we see that any automorphism of $F/L$ extends to an automorphism of $F/K$, therefore $Aut(F/L) \subset Aut(F/K)$ and by the definition of $L$ : $Aut(F/L)= G$.

For any $c \in F$, let $f_c(x) = \prod_{\sigma \in G} (x-\sigma(c))$ which is a polynomial of $F[x]$. Note that each of its coefficients are fixed by $G$, therefore $f_c \in L[x]$. Thus, the minimal polynomial of $c$ over $L$ divides $f_c$ whose roots are $\sigma(c)\in F$.

This means that $F/L$ is Galois and $r = [F:L] = |Aut(F/L)| = m$ (write $L = F(b_1,\ldots,b_k)$ and use induction on $k$)

---

Assume $m=n$, then $L=K$ and $F/K$ is Galois.

---

If $\{\sigma(a)\}_{\sigma \in G}$ is a $K$-vector space basis of $F$, then $n=[F:K] \le m$ and by the preceding $n=m$ which means that [$F/K$ is Galois](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_extension#Characterization_of_Galois_extensions)